# How to use vlookup with values that aren't numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am trying to use vlookup to find the sales rep with the highest revenue within my data set. I am getting an error message saying the value being found is not a number (which is the sales rep's name). Not sure how to fix this issue.

I have read Index/Match formulas that may work but I am not sure how to use them.

```
=VLOOKUP(L6,DATA!E:E,DATA!C:C,false)
```

> `#VALUE!`  Function VLOOKUP parameter 3 expects number values. But 'JESSE CAMIRE' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(L6, {DATA!E:E, DATA!C:C}, 2, 0)
```

if **L6** is found in **DATA!E:E** vlookup will return value from **2**nd column eg. **DATA!C:C** but only if an exact match is found hence **0**

Comment: **2** is 2nd column from {DATA!E:E, DATA!C:C} eg. C column. and **0** is "only exact match"